# Creating pivot in excel using vba fails when there are more data

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel:-

[image]

My VBA Code to create Pivot:-

```
Sub Macro10()
'
' Macro10 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R20C4", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Sheet2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
End Sub
```

The above creates Pivot, but when there are more/fewer rows in the excel, it gives an error.

Comment: What's error content you get ? Not sure but I think you have to delete the newly added pivot area before creating.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically find the last used row in a sheet, try the following.

```
Ways To Find The Last Row

Sub FindingLastRow()
'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Using SpecialCells Function
  LastRow = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

To find the last column, try the following.

```
Ways To Find The Last Column

Sub FindingLastColumn()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last column number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(7, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastColumn = sht.UsedRange.Columns(sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

'Using Table Range
  LastColumn = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastColumn = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Columns.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Right (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastColumn = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

End Sub
```

Resource:

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Also, turn on the Macro Recorder and click through the steps you need to do.  All the necessary code will be generated for you.  You will get a lot more code than you need, but that's fine, because you can simply trim out the sections you don't need.  With the mouse, click inside the Macro code and hit the F8 key over and over to step through the code, line by line.  Do that, and you will learn a ton!  Do some smart Google searches on things you don't understand to fill in the gaps.  In a few days you will be an expert with this stuff.

Here is a good link for you to get started with.

https://www.contextures.com/excel-vba-pivot-table-field-list.html